# lower() in where clause does not match pattern

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, postgresql-9.3

```
select version();
                                                   version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.14 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

query:

```
select foreign_text
, lower(t.foreign_text) = 'спорт' c1
, convert_to(lower(t.foreign_text),'utf8') = convert_to(lower('спорт'),'utf8') c2
from translation_keywords_from_ru_to_en t
where
  lower(t.foreign_text) = 'спорт'
;
 foreign_text | c1 | c2
--------------+----+----
(0 rows)
```

removing `lower` in `where`, leaving in column list:

```
select foreign_text
, lower(t.foreign_text) = 'спорт' c1
, convert_to(lower(t.foreign_text),'utf8') = convert_to(lower('спорт'),'utf8') c2
from translation_keywords_from_ru_to_en t
where
  t.foreign_text = 'спорт'
;
 foreign_text | c1 | c2
--------------+----+----
 спорт        | t  | t
 спорт        | t  | t
(2 rows)
```

mind that *c1* (`lower(t.foreign_text) = 'спорт'`) is `true`, while it apparently was not in previous select in `WHERE` clause.

Also true:

```
where lower(t.foreign_text collate "fr_FR") = 'спорт'
where initcap(t.foreign_text) = initcap('спорт')
where convert_to(lower(t.foreign_text),'utf8') = convert_to(lower('спорт'),'utf8')
where upper(t.foreign_text) = upper('спорт')
```

but false:

```
where lower(t.foreign_text) = 'спорт'
where lower(t.foreign_text) = lower('спорт')
```

I did [not find anything specific](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) for `lower()`. If I convert `lower(t.foreign_text)` to "utf bytea", phenomena disappears.

**My situation**: as soon as query `insert into ... where not exists (... where lower(t.foreign_text) = lower('спорт'))` fails to find rows it tries to insert duplicates. I see how to rewrite the query to avoid it. Yet I'm confused.

**Question**: Am I missing smth and `lower(t.foreign_text) = 'спорт'` can be false in `where`, but `true` in column list OR I hit some sort of bug?

`foreign_text` is of `text` type

```
\l+ db
                                               List of databases
  Name  | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges |  Size  | Tablespace | Description
--------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+--------+------------+-------------
      db|     un| UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                   | 406 GB | pg_default
```

|

Comment: what is datatype of foriegn_text ?

Comment: sorry - should have mention - it is text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only explanation that I can come up with is that you have an index `ON translation_keywords_from_ru_to_en (lower(foreign_text))`, but that index is corrupt.

Do you get the same results if you run the following before the query:

```
SET enable_indexscan = off;
SET enable_indexonlyscan = off;
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;
```

This will avoid using indexes with the query.

Comment: yes - disabling indexscan removed the phenomena - I should have get to this myself - shame on me. thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to find out what corrupted the index.

Comment: the db came from dying hardware